# When will onDraw actually be called?

Tags: android, ondraw, invalidation

I have some code like this:

```
@Override 
public void onPress() {
    ...
    Log.v(tag, "hi");
    invalidate(0, 0, 100, 100);
    ...
}
```

The above tow lines of code reside in a callback function called by android system, specifically, `KeyboardView`.

But I find that in some cases, the view will not be redrawn although the string `"hi"` is outputted.

My question is, eventually when will the `onDraw` be called ? After my function returns or at some point in the future? And how can I make sure the call to `invalidate` above will make effect?

Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: do you have Log.v in onDraw ?

Comment: @pskink yes, but there's no output. I can only see "hi"

Comment: what if you replace invalidate(0, 0, 100, 100); with invalidate() ?

Comment: it's the same result.

Comment: i think you would neeed to post more code

Comment: I have found another approach to invalidate it, but I still wanna know the answers for questions. Just ignore my code please.